# Calculate difference in days given values from two columns

Tags: python, pandas, function, datetime

I am trying to calculate the difference in days between when the value in one column (`One`) is `1` and value in another column (`Value`) is greater than `0`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['02.01.2017', '03.01.2017', '04.01.2017', '05.01.2017', '01.01.2017', '02.01.2017', '03.01.2017', '02.12.2017', '03.12.2017', '04.12.2017'],
                   'CustomerId':['02','02','02','02','03','03','03', '05', '05', '05'],
                   'Value':[0, 0, 10, 100, 0, 10000, 10000, 0, 0, 12312312],
                   'One':[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]})

def dayDiff(groupby):
    if (not (groupby['One'] == 1).any()) or (not (groupby['Value'] > 0).any()):
        return np.zeros(groupby['Date'].count())

    min_date = groupby[groupby['One'] == 1]['Date'].iloc[0]
    max_date = groupby[groupby['Value'] > 0]['Date'].iloc[0]
    delta = max_date - min_date
    return np.where(groupby['Value'] > 0 , delta.days, 0)


df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
DateDiff = df.groupby('CustomerId').apply(dayDiff).explode().rename('DateDiff').reset_index(drop=True)
df = pd.concat([df, DateDiff], axis=1)
df
```

The result is:

```
          Date  CustomerId     Value    One DateDiff
0   2017-01-02          02         0    1   0
1   2017-01-03          02         0    1   0
2   2017-01-04          02        10    0   2
3   2017-01-05          02       100    0   2
4   2017-01-01          03         0    1   0
5   2017-01-02          03     10000    0   1
6   2017-01-03          03     10000    0   1
7   2017-12-02          05         0    1   0
8   2017-12-03          05         0    0   0
9   2017-12-04          05  12312312    0   2
```

The problem is that row 2 displays the wrong value. I expect it to display value `1`, and row 6 to display `2`. Because I want to calculate the difference in days between the last `1` value in `One` with respective to the customer when `Value` is greater than zero. It seems like `dayDiff()` calculates the same difference in days regardless of the dates.

I tried changing `iloc[0]` values, but the result wasn't entirely correct.

Expectations (Notice that row 2 and 6 of `DateDiff` are now correct):

```
          Date  CustomerId     Value    One DateDiff
0   2017-01-02          02         0    1   0
1   2017-01-03          02         0    1   0
2   2017-01-04          02        10    0   1
3   2017-01-05          02       100    0   2
4   2017-01-01          03         0    1   0
5   2017-01-02          03     10000    0   1
6   2017-01-03          03     10000    0   2
7   2017-12-02          05         0    1   0
8   2017-12-03          05         0    0   0
9   2017-12-04          05  12312312    0   2
```

Edit: Using @jezrael's suggestions, I realised there is a problem when there are multiple `1`'s beyond. The days become negative. I want row `2` to display 0 because `2017-01-04` - `2017-01-04` should be zero, as it is the last date. In other words, the last date before or the same date.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['02.01.2017', '03.01.2017', '04.01.2017', '05.01.2017', '01.01.2017', '02.01.2017', '03.01.2017', '02.12.2017', '03.12.2017', '04.12.2017'],
                   'CustomerId':['02','02','02','02','03','03','03', '05', '05', '05'],
                   'Value':[0, 0, 10, 100, 0, 10000, 10000, 0, 0, 12312312],
                   'One':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]})

        Date CustomerId     Value  One  DateDiff
0 2017-01-02         02         0    1         0
1 2017-01-03         02         0    1         0
2 2017-01-04         02        10    1        -1
3 2017-01-05         02       100    1         0
4 2017-01-01         03         0    1         0
5 2017-01-02         03     10000    0         1
6 2017-01-03         03     10000    0         2
7 2017-12-02         05         0    1         0
8 2017-12-03         05         0    0         0
9 2017-12-04         05  12312312    0         2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need difference of last value `Date` with of `One == 1` with all values with `Value > 0` per groups:

```
def dayDiff(groupby):
    if (not (groupby['One'] == 1).any()) or (not (groupby['Value'] > 0).any()):
        groupby['DateDiff'] = 0
        return groupby

    min_date = groupby.loc[groupby['One'] == 1, 'Date'].iloc[-1]
    max_date = groupby.loc[groupby['Value'] > 0, 'Date']
    delta = max_date - min_date
    groupby['DateDiff'] = delta.dt.days.reindex(groupby.index, fill_value=0)
    return groupby

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df = df.groupby('CustomerId').apply(dayDiff)
print (df)
        Date CustomerId     Value  One  DateDiff
0 2017-01-02         02         0    1         0
1 2017-01-03         02         0    1         0
2 2017-01-04         02        10    0         1
3 2017-01-05         02       100    0         2
4 2017-01-01         03         0    1         0
5 2017-01-02         03     10000    0         1
6 2017-01-03         03     10000    0         2
7 2017-12-02         05         0    1         0
8 2017-12-03         05         0    0         0
9 2017-12-04         05  12312312    0         2
```

EDIT: Another idea is filter rows before `groupby` by mask and then `append` rows which not match:

```
def dayDiff(groupby):
    if (not (groupby['One'] == 1).any()) or (not (groupby['Value'] > 0).any()):
        groupby['DateDiff'] = 0
        return groupby

    min_date = groupby.loc[groupby['One'] == 1, 'Date'].iloc[-1]
    max_date = groupby.loc[groupby['Value'] > 0, 'Date']
    delta = max_date - min_date
    groupby['DateDiff'] = delta.dt.days.reindex(groupby.index, fill_value=0)
    return groupby

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
m1 = (df['One'] == 1) & (df['Value'] <= 0)
m2 = (df['Value'] > 0) & (df['One'] != 1)
mask = m1 | m2

df = df[mask].groupby('CustomerId').apply(dayDiff).append(df[~mask], sort=False).sort_index()
df['DateDiff'] = df['DateDiff'].fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
        Date CustomerId     Value  One  DateDiff
0 2017-01-02         02         0    1         0
1 2017-01-03         02         0    1         0
2 2017-01-04         02        10    1         0
3 2017-01-05         02       100    1         0
4 2017-01-01         03         0    1         0
5 2017-01-02         03     10000    0         1
6 2017-01-03         03     10000    0         2
7 2017-12-02         05         0    1         0
8 2017-12-03         05         0    0         0
9 2017-12-04         05  12312312    0         2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I noticed a problem when there are multiple values of `1`, as I have shown in the edit of my main post. How do I change the code such that the function calculates the difference until the same date (ignoring dates beyond the same date where `Value` is `>0`)?

Comment: @Mataunited18 - Not 100% sure if understand, but I try edit answer.

Comment: Great edit. You understand me fully, but seems like I get `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds` for my population set. I tried changing the `if` function back to the code in my original post, but with no success. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use `idxmin` with `transform` to find location of first `0`, subtract `1` is location of last `1` in each group and assign to `s`. Slicing on `s` and subtracting from `df.Date`. Finally, use `where` to flip to `0` on `df.Value=0`

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d.%m.%Y')
s = df.groupby('CustomerId').One.transform('idxmin').sub(1)
s1 = df.Date.sub(df.loc[s, ['Date']].reset_index(drop=True)['Date']).dt.days

df['DateDiff'] = s1.where(df.Value.gt(0), 0)

Out[363]:
        Date CustomerId     Value  One  DateDiff
0 2017-01-02         02         0    1         0
1 2017-01-03         02         0    1         0
2 2017-01-04         02        10    0         1
3 2017-01-05         02       100    0         2
4 2017-01-01         03         0    1         0
5 2017-01-02         03     10000    0         1
6 2017-01-03         03     10000    0         2
7 2017-12-02         05         0    1         0
8 2017-12-03         05         0    0         0
9 2017-12-04         05  12312312    0         2
```